# WebGL/three.js fragment shader - Overlay alpha-transparent texture with alpha-transparent colour

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl, shader

So I have a texture passed to a fragment shader, and I want to overlay a colour with 50% alpha on top of it. I've got it half working, but the original texture loses it's alpha.

See:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {
    vec4 tColor = texture2D(texture, vUv);

    vec4 color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(tColor.rgb, color.rgb, color.a), 1.0);
}
```

It's obvious here that the texture's alpha isn't taken into account in `gl_FragColor`, but I'm not sure how to integrate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(tColor.rgb, color.rgb, color.a), 1.0);
```

The last argument you're passing in, `1.0`, is the alpha, and you're hard coding it to 1.

Comment: Oh balls. Yeah this is what I wanted: `gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(tColor.rgb, color.rgb, color.a), tColor.a);`